# My cactus is turning brown on top. Is this usual?

Tags: watering, cactus

[image]

I've just bought this cactus and it's turning brown. I'm wondering if it's because I watered it too much or because of the changing weather? (We rarely have cold days here and it's started to get cold this week) or because of other thing???

Comment: I'm having trouble spotting any brown in the photo, maybe you could take a photo with the light behind you rather than in front? Also a bit confused because you say you've only just bought the cactus, so not  sure how you could have overwatered - how long, precisely, have you had it?

Comment: Like @Bamboo said, please try to take a different photo, preferably, focusing on the brown. I've had it happen on the drive home in winter, but only where the temperature is below freezing.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience with cacti it is usually too much water, especially if watering in the Winter.  If caught in time the plant may survive.  The temperature would need to drop below freezing to cause this problem.